# Windows 8 can't access second internal HDD

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

I have two HDD one of them is 500 GB (SYSTEM), other one is 1 TB (Entertainment). Sadly Windows 8 doesn't see my second HDD. I can see it on BIOS, Ubuntu Live CD but not on Windows 8 strange... Other strange thing is I can see the second HDD on disk management but no name and no drive letter. It's located but it has 100% free space but I'm using it nearly 600 GB.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you initialized the drive and partitioned it yet? I'm assuming this is a new hard drive as they all come un-partitioned.

Comment: No. It isn't a new HDD I partitioned hdd before on ubuntu. Now in this HDD I have lots of files nearly 600 GB. I can post a screenshot of gparted from ubuntu live usb. And by the way the context menu in disk management is blank only delete partition visible.